# Nema34 stepper motor heating

Tags: arduino

We are using a Nema 34 stepper motor driving it using Leadshine M542 driver and arduino UNO.
24 V voltage and 4.2 A peak current being given.
Our motor lifts a metal frame for about a minute (it has to rotate about 1minute) and needs to hold it the 4-5 hours at fixed position.
Now it draws the same current when its running( lifting) and while its holding which makes it a continuously current drawing motor and becomes heated extremely as time goes.
Kindly suggest me a solution.

Comment: using a motor that can handle this current without overheating, use a current limiting resistor in drivers in order to avoid overheating!

Comment: is there any possibility to control the current using arduino programming?

Comment: What have you set the driver SW1-3 to?

Comment: sw1-off,sw2-off,sw3-off

Comment: @Dhans - **no, don't use a resistor**.  This is not the 1970's.  The specs of the question already make it evident that a *current mode* drive is being used, what should happen is that the programmed current should be set appropriately, and then backed off if the holding torque is less.

Comment: @AshokreddySingam - this doesn't really sound like a stepper motor application.  Can you use a gearmotor instead?

Comment: @Chris Stratton, yes. You are right. Then using a motor with handling of this current rating without over heating might be a choice

Comment: @Dhans No, you adjust the current setting to be suitable for the motor for the duration of time that it will be applied, which potentially means changing the setting dynamically.  But first you choose a motor appropriate to the job, which does not seem to have happened here.

Answer (score 0):

From the driver manual:

[image]

Try changing SW4 or limit the dynamic current. I guess you have calculated how much current (torque) you actually need? Also, you could see excessive current draw if you wire up the motor totally wrong. See section 5 in the manual. It also mentions how to set the motor current depending on coil configuration.